# problema con app de html y javascript: Failed to resolve module specifier "web3".Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, blockchain

Estoy intentando ejecutar una aplicación de html y javascript que utiliza un **import** y me está generando ese error:
**Failed to resolve module specifier "web3".Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".**

El código es cuestión es:

`import Web3 from "web3";`

Tengo creado un proyecto npm, con su package.json y su carpeta node_modules donde está instalado web3. Pero no se como solucionar el error de esa ruta. No se que alternativas existen.

Yo antes usaba webpack y funcionaba correctamente, pero ahora quería poner la aplicación en un servicio de hosting y no tengo claro como hacerlo.

Comment: Te está diciendo que tienes que ponerle la ruta, puede ser que tengas incluido node pero que en tu proyecto haya generado una carpeta virtual con nodemodules y se encuentre fuera del proyecto, también puede que sea que tengas que añadir la ruta relativa hacia el módulo `/Carpeta/web3`

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Para ello necesitamos que nos muestres el listado o estructura de los directorios. En particular, te está indicando que no es capaz de encontrar `web3.js` en el mismo directorio que hace el `import`.